# Cup-product of the torus is nonzero

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I calculated the singular cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$H^n(S^1 \times S^1) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} & \text{if } n = 0,2 \\
\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} & \text{if } n = 1 \\
0 & \text{if } n > 2
\end{cases}$$

I want to know how to prove, that one of these cup-products

$$\cup:H^1(S^1\times S^1)\otimes H^1(S^1\times S^1)\to H^2(S^1\times S^1),\; [\alpha]\cup [\beta]=[\alpha\cup \beta]$$ or

$$\cup:H^0(S^1\times S^1)\otimes H^1(S^1\times S^1)\to H^1(S^1\times S^1),\; [\alpha]\cup [\beta]=[\alpha\cup \beta]$$ is nonzero?

Comment: You're going to have trouble proving this because it's not true... like you said, $H^2(S^1) = 0$.

Comment: oh!! you are right, thanks!! I will change this!

Comment: oh no, I meant an other topological space... I'm too tired

Comment: Suppose $M$ is a path-connected space. Then $H^0(M) \cong \Bbb Z$, and you can canonically identify the cup product map $H^0(M) \otimes H^k(M) \to H^k(M)$ with multiplication.

Comment: ok, iff I consider $M=S^1\times S^1$ instead of $S^1$, can I argue that this multiplication is nonzero?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you carefully read Example 3.7. in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. And by carefully I mean really carefully and multiple times. It explains the case for a closed surface of genus $\geq 1$, and for $=1$ you get $S^1 \times S^1$. It covers the topic really well. If you want more intuition you can also read his introduction to cohomology (ch. 3).

Comment: ok, thanks. I will do that!!